# How to remove only one url .html in .htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, unix

I have a url similar to below

```
www.test.com/products.html
```

I want this to work when someone type `www.test.com/products` (without .html)

I only want to do this this file and the rest has to work as normal. I know how to do this for all html files as below and works ok.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

I have not much idea about unix stuff. Can someone help ? only the www.test.com/products should call the www.test.com/products.html.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products/?$ products.html
```

Add any [**flags**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html) as you see fit.